# Does the nerve of a category have the following stronger lifting property?

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff

Definition:

- For integer $k\geq0$ we let $\Delta^k := \mathrm{Hom}_{\text{FinitePosets(Nonstrict)}}(-\;,\;[k]=\{0,1,\ldots,k\})$ denote the usual simplicial-set model of the $k$-simplex.
- For integer $k>0$,
  let $v_i : \Delta^0 \rightarrow \Delta^1$ be obtained (via Yoneda) from the maps $[0] \rightarrow [1]$ sending $0$ to $i$ for each $i\in\{0,1\}$,
  and define $L_k$ to be the following colimit in simplicial sets:
  $$ L_k := \mathrm{colim} \left( 
  \Delta^1 \xleftarrow{v_1} \Delta^0 \xrightarrow{v_0} \Delta^1
  \xleftarrow{v_1} \Delta^0 \xrightarrow{v_0} \Delta^1
  \cdots \Delta^1 \xleftarrow{v_1} \Delta^0 \xrightarrow{v_0} \Delta^1
  \right)
  $$
  where the number of $\Delta^0$ factors is $k-1$ (so the number of $\Delta^1$'s is $k$), and the colimit is taken in simplicial sets.
  (Rmk: we can also define $L_0 := \Delta^0$ if we wish.)

  So, $L_k$ is the simplicial-set model for the directed graph $\bullet \to \bullet \to \cdots \to \bullet$ where there are $k$ edges (so $k+1$ vertices).
- For each integer $k$, for integer $j$ with $0\leq j\leq k-1$,
  let $e_j : \Delta^1 \rightarrow \Delta^n$
  be obtained (via Yoneda) from the map $[1] \rightarrow [n]$
  which sends $0,1$ to $j,j+1$.
  These data combine to give a simplicial-set morphism $L_k \rightarrow \Delta^k$. This should be a simplicial-set mononomorphism.

  We can view $L_k$ as a "maximal directed 1-chain (with no vertex repetition)", in $\Delta^k$.
- Let us say a given simplicial set $X$ has property $\mathscr{P}$ if
  for every integer $k\geq0$,
  every simplicial-set morphism $L_k \rightarrow X$ can lift along $L_k \rightarrow \Delta^k$ to give some simplicial-set morphism $\Delta^k \rightarrow X$.

---

My question is:

> If $X = N(C)$ is the standard nerve of a 1-category $C$, then does $X$ have property $\mathscr{P}$?

Notes:

- We already know that if $X = N(C)$ then $X$ has the lifting property for the inner-horn inclusions $\Lambda_i^k \rightarrow \Delta^k$, for $0<i<k$. I.e., $N(C)$ is a quasicategory.
- We note also that if $k\geq2$ and $0<i <k$, or $k\geq3$ and $0\leq i \leq k$,
  then $L_k$ "sits inside" $\Lambda_i^k$.
- If $X = N(C)$ does have property $\mathscr{P}$, then in fact the lifting of a morphism $L_k \rightarrow N(C)$ to a morphism $\Delta^k \rightarrow N(C)$ should be unique. This is because every $k$-cell in $N(C)$ is a composable chain of $k$ many arrows of $C$, the cell determined by the list of arrows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're describing the [spine](https://kerodon.net/tag/00JA) of a simplex.  The inclusion of the spine into the simplex [is inner anodyne](https://kerodon.net/tag/00J6), so there is a bijection $\operatorname{Hom}(\Delta^k, X) \to \operatorname{Hom}(L_k, X)$ whenever $X$ is the nerve of an ordinary category; see [here](https://kerodon.net/tag/00J2). In other words, given a map $L_k \to X$, an extension to $\Delta^k \to X$ exists and is unique.  Briefly, the proof is just to repeatedly use the horn-filling property you mentioned to fill in the rest of the simplex from the spine.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!